# Why is $\cot x \cos x - \csc x = -\sin x$ true?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, trigonometry

While working on a Calculus homework sheet I came to

$\frac{d}{dx} (\cot(x/2)\sin(x/2))$.

After a little bit of work and simplifying, I got to

$-1/2(\cot(x/2)\cos(x/2) - \csc(x/2))$.

I wanted to simplify this further, but was confused when, upon plugging this into a calculator, it lines up exactly with $-1/2(\sin(x/2))$. This can be generalized as

$\cot(x)\cos(x)-\csc(x)=-\sin(x)$.

I don't see why this is, as I can't seem to spot a hidden correlation based in the definitions of these trig functions, and I attempted multiple times to rearrange and simplify this further, with no luck. I asked several of my more math-savvy friends and they weren't sure either. Even when I tried searching online for a reasoning behind this, I found little to nothing.

So, why is this true? I'm definitely missing something obvious here, I just can't tell what that is.

Comment: Use `\cos`, `\csc` and `\sin` so they come out in the correct typeface.

Comment: Multiplying through by $\sin x$ yields a well-known formula...

Comment: @abiessu what would that formula be? I must be overthinking this. How would I know to multiply by $\sin(x)$?

Comment: You don't have to know; you can just do the operation, writing everything in terms of sines and cosines.

Comment: $\cot x=\frac {\cos x}{\sin x},\csc x=\frac 1{\sin x}$, so that multiplication yields $\cos^2x-1=-\sin^2x$ which is more commonly viewed as $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align*}
\cot x\cos x - \csc x &= \left(\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\right)\cos x - \frac{1}{\sin x}\\
&= \frac{\cos^2x - 1}{\sin x}\\
&= \frac{-\sin^2 x}{\sin x}\\
&= -\sin (x).
\end{align*}$$

Note however that this equality is only true if $x\neq n\pi$ for $n$ an integer, since the left hand side is not defined at those points, but the right hand side is defined.

Comment: Oh, wow! That was incredibly simple, I don't know how I missed that! Thanks mate.